# MySQL Where IN AND on the same column

Tags: mysql

I am looking the client who has tag `Kane` and `Andrew`.

How do i put it in the query?

> I am expecting the output to be `Client ID 1` only

```
INSERT INTO `client` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Client 1'),
  ('2', 'Client 2'),
  ('3', 'Client 3'),
  ('4', 'Client 4');

 INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`, `client_id`, `tag`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'Kane'),
  ('2', '1', 'Andrew'),
  ('3', '2', 'Andrew'),
  ('4', '3', 'Kane'),
  ('5', '3', 'James'),
  ('6', '4', 'Andrew');

## mysql query
select * from client where 
exists (
select client_id 
    from tag 
    where tag.client_id = client.id 
    and (tag  = 'Kane' and tag = 'Andrew')
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48955/55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following query to get the desired results

```
select c.*
from client c
join tag t on t.client_id = c.id 
where t.tag in ('Kane','Andrew')
group by c.id 
having count(distinct t.id) = 2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48955/59)

OR

```
select c.*
from client c
join tag t on t.client_id = c.id 
group by c.id 
having sum(t.tag = 'Kane')
and sum(t.tag = 'Andrew')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48955/63)

Answer (score 3):

First find the `client_id` having both the names using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. Then join it with the first table to get the `name`.

**Query**

```
select t1.`name`
from `client` t1
join (
    select `client_id` from `tag`
    where `tag` in ('Kane','Andrew')
    group by `client_id`
    having count(*) = 2
) t2
on t1.`id` = t2.`client_id`;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09c0f4/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Here are some queries without a group by

This one is with INNER JOIN only

```
SELECT client.* 
FROM client 
INNER JOIN tag tag1
ON tag1.client_id = client.id
INNER JOIN tag tag2
ON tag2.client_id = client.id
WHERE tag1.tag = 'Kane'
AND tag2.tag = 'Andrew'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8461bd/5)

This one is with subqueries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client 
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM tag WHERE tag.client_id = client.id AND tag.tag = 'Kane')
AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM tag WHERE tag.client_id = client.id AND tag.tag = 'Andrew')
```

Both queries can benefit from an index

```
ALTER TABLE tag ADD KEY LOOKUP (tag , client_id)
```